# Why I am getting full code of user defined command in rmarkdown?

Tags: rmarkdown

```
---
documentclass: report
classoption: twoside
fontsize: 12pt
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \newcommand{\zero}{\centerline{\tikz{\node[circle, fill=gray, minimum size=0.4\linewidth] {};}}}
---
\zero
```

I am wondering why in the tex file I am not getting

```
\begin{document}
\zero
\end{document}
```

instead I get the full code

```
\begin{document}
\centerline{\tikz{\node[circle, fill=gray, minimum size=0.4\linewidth] {};}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Macros with `\newcommnad` are expanded when exported. Not sure why, because this is exactly what LaTeX will also make, but if this is a problem, note that macros with `\def` are not expanded. However, you must be aware that careless use of `\def` could have unexpected consequences.